# Trying to get Django and jQuery working together to add/remove bookmarks via an “Add/Remove Bookmark” link

Tags: jquery, django

I’m learning Django by building  a simple Q&A site. The model, url, view and template code below adds/removes bookmarks from the database as required…

```
Model:

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

Url:

url(r'^add_remove_bookmark/(\d+)/(\d+)/$', views.add_remove_bookmark),

View:

@login_required
def add_remove_bookmark(request, uid, qid):
    try:
        bookmark = Bookmark.objects.get(user=uid, question=qid)
        bookmark.delete()
    except Bookmark.DoesNotExist:
        bookmark = Bookmark.objects.create(
                       user=User.objects.get(id=uid),
                       question=Question.objects.get(id=qid))
        bookmark.save()    
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/qa/answers/' + qid)

Template:
<a href="/qa/add_remove_bookmark/{{ user.id }}/{{ question.id }}/">Add Bookmark</a>
```

And this jQuery code toggles the link between “Add Bookmark” and “Remove Bookmark” if I modify my template  tag to include class=”add-remove-bookmark”. But once I add class=”” to the  tag clicking the link fails to update the database.

```
jQuery:

    $(".add-remove-bookmark").click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).html() == "Add Bookmark") {
            $(this).html('Remove Bookmark');
        }
        else {
            $(this).html('Add Bookmark');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Bottom line, I want users to click “Add Bookmark” and have the code add the bookmark to the database AND toggle the link to “Remove Bookmark”. And vice versa. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Related question – I think I need a way to test – from within my template – if a bookmark exists for a question so I can display the correct initial value for the toggle link: Ie Add if it doesn’t exist, otherwise Remove. I tried to think of a function I could add to my Question model (eg Question.user_has_bookmarked) but couldn’t come up with anything that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return false;` statement at the end of your click handler prevents the browser from actually following the link. Removing this should allow your click to follow the link and hit your view as expected.

For testing if a bookmark exists, you can use a call like `Bookmark.objects.filter(user=request.user, question__id=quid).exists()` in your view that renders the template in question and pass the returned value to the template as `bookmark_exists`. This would allow you to do the following in your template:

```
<a href="/qa/add_remove_bookmark/{{ user.id }}/{{ question.id }}/">{% if bookmark_exists %}Remove{% else %}Add{% endif %} Bookmark</a>
```

---

A couple of side notes:

- The code here is using a `GET` request to modify data. It would be semantically more correct to use `POST` and `DELETE` in this case because these verbs correspond to what you're looking to accomplish. Refer to [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Request_methods) for a list of HTTP methods that would be worth knowing about in these cases.
- The view as shown would allow any user to create or delete a bookmark for any user. It's most likely the case that it should instead use the `request.user` variable to refer only to the logged in user. This would prevent some undesirable behavior related to sharing links, etc.

Comment: VERY helpful. I removed return false and added a variable bookmark_exists to my answers.html view (since Add/Remove Bookmark is called from answers.html). That allowed me to display the correct link text (Add or Remove). So with those two changes it's all working as I had hoped. I also incorporated request.user per your suggestion to ensure users can only add/remove their own bookmarks. I will research POST and DELETE and adjust my view accordingly.

Comment: @jonafato can you please help with a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384218/how-to-bookmark-a-page-in-django