# How to bookmark a page in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to edit an html page so a logged in user can favorite / bookmark a `video.id`

Here is the **.html** file

```
<td>
    <form method='POST' action="{% url 'researcher_view_app:favourite_post' video.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='video' value={{ video.id }}>
        <button type='submit'>Bookmark</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Here is the **urls.py** file

```
path('<int:fav_id>/favourite_post', views.favourite_post, name='favourite_post'),
```

Here is the **view.py** file

```
def favourite_post(request, fav_id):
    video = get_object_or_404(Video, id=fav_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video.

   return render(request, 'researcher_view_app/%s' % fav_id)
```

Comment: thank you downvoter with no explanation

Comment: What's your mechanism to store a "favorite" here, another model class? There's not enough information in this question to provide an answer to a specific question. Please add enough context so that someone can point you toward a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you modify the **models.py** that has the user models

```
class ProjectUser(AbstractUser):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Images)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

- In the **.html file** add the following:

```
{% for image in available_images %}
/* show image */
<form method='post' action="{% url 'user-image-add' %}">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type='hidden' name='image' value={{image.id}}>
 <button type='submit'>bookmark</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

- In your **views.py** add the following method

```
def user_image_add(request):
    user_image_form = ImageForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and user_image_form.is_valid(): 
         request.user.images.add(user_image_form.cleaned_data['image'])
         return JsonResponse(status=200)
    raise Http404()
```

- Create a **forms.py** file in your add and add the following:

```
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Images.objects.all())
```

To show those bookmarked images you can just iterate over `request.user.images` (it gives you a QS of Images) similar to code above.

---

- In the **urls.py** add the following:

`path('user-image-add/', views.user_image_add, 'user-image-add')`

- In models.py add a method in User model for getting bool if video is bookmarked

```
def is_bookmarked(self, video_id): 
    return self.bookmarked_videos.filter(id=video_id).exists()
```

simirlarly `is_bookmarked` can be added to Video model accepting user_id and checking `video.projectuser_set`.

And add the following to your .html file where users bookmarked a video

```
`{% if video.is_bookmarked %}`
```

---

- Delete the `UserProfile` as you do not need it. Just make sure to have needed instance in context of view.

Comment: i updated answer to bookmark images. Considering you have a model for Video somewhere in your code, I think you need to make m2m to it and just have `Video.image = FileField` to show to user.

Comment: i find func based views way simpler to deal with, if you want cbv you can decide what class to inherit yourself and redo it, it's only a couple of lines.

Comment: edited my answer to answer your updated question on how to check if a video is bookmarked

Comment: updated it. Next you should put the code in your project and fix small things that are not visible on the scale of SO question yourself.

Comment: image.id is in form body, it's available in request.POST if you want to get raw data. Form parses it, validates and saves to 'cleaned_data' once `is_valid` is called

Comment: fill it with something.`{'foo':'bar'}`

Comment: Sorry ! But this answer is actually wrong for multiple reasons.